# What is the best way to display a UIView at the top of the screen in either iOS 6.1 or 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, ios7

Here is a simple program to display a blue colored view at the top of the screen.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

  UIViewController* vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
  CGFloat y = 20;
  if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    y = 0;
  }
  UIView* sample = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, 768, 100)];
  sample.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  [vc.view addSubview:sample];

  self.window.rootViewController = vc;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

I have logic in there to set the y variable to either 0 or 20 if iOS version is 7 or 6 and under.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The ios7 guide includes some new properties which may be set on the controller that allows the view to account for the status bar.  But, since its NDA'd, I'll refer you to their document which is accessible from the dev portal.

Comment: Have you tried simply pinning it to the top?

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 brings several changes to how you lay out and customize the appearance of your UI. The changes in view-controller layout, tint color, and font affect all the UIKit objects in your app. In addition, enhancements to gesture recognizer APIs give you finer grained control over gesture interactions.

Please refer, [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I decided to do exactly as you've mentioned. It is not "as clean as", it takes more work, but it gives you a fine precision, in case you're not targeting too many devices.